# Run shell script with parameter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I know how to run a script from within Ruby. I usually use back ticks and they work fine. Recently we got request to feed one more argument to the script and problem happens here.

Originally, it looks like this:
a global variable defined as:

```
SCRIPT = "/opt/customer/send_command.pl"
```

Then, we call

```
status =`"#{SCRIPT}" -c "ctl.pl qstatus"`
queue = `"#{SCRIPT}" -c "ctl.pl queue"`
```

Everything is fine. 
Now, there's one more parameter to feed in the script send_command.pl. So I changed global variable SCRIPT to:

```
SCRIPT = "/opt/customer/send_command.pl -p production"
```

And I use the same way to call that script:

```
status =`"#{SCRIPT}" -c "ctl.pl qstatus"`
```

But I got the error message:

```
sh: /opt/customer/send_command.pl -p production: not found
```

If I ditch SCRIPT variable, just call the script directly like:

```
status = `/opt/customer/send_command.pl -p production -c "ctl.pl qstatus"`
```

and it works as expected.

My question is why that happens and how to fix it? I guess I could just manually put -p production everywhere, but it's less ideal and very error prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It didn't work because you have extra double quotes. To fix it, remove them.

```
status =`#{SCRIPT} -c "ctl.pl qstatus"`
```

Comment: Interestingly, running `"ls"`, `"pwd"` (with the extra double quotes) in the shell all work just fine on OSX.

Comment: Yeyeye. I was just noticing the `SCRIPT = "/opt/customer/send_command.pl -p production"` part. That assuredly wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the double quotes:

from:

```
status =`"#{SCRIPT}" -c "ctl.pl qstatus"`
```

to

```
status =`#{SCRIPT} -c "ctl.pl qstatus"`
```

unless you want to try escaping them like:

```
status ="#{SCRIPT} -c \"ctl.pl qstatus\""
```